# What kind of Non-ECC RAM does this board support?

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

I'm leaning towards a purchase of this CPU/MOBO combo:

- [SUPERMICRO MBD-X9DRL-IF-B](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813182670)
- [Xeon E5-2660 2.2GHz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0090EMI48) x 2 (if I think I can afford two...)

### Background

I'm trying to figure out what kind of and how much RAM to get. I understand most of the implications of the particular processor I'm aiming to get, but I'm having some trouble understanding the manual, which I believe I found [on SuperMicro's site](http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C606_602/MNL-1298.pdf).  Though it doesn't speak to CPU or RAM *type*, this table on `2-12` *(pdf p36)* leads me to believe that I can use 1 processor with 4 DIMMS, so that's good:

[image: Processor and Memory Module Population Table]

And this quote indicates clearly that with my processor choice, I cannot use 1866 MHz memory:

> 1866 MHz memory speed is dependent on Intel E5-2600v2
>   CPUs

...so that's fine.

### My Issue

However, the first table on page `2-14` (p38) is slightly confusing to me. I think my main issue is understanding some of the abbreviations and jargon used in the table (like "Ranks", "Data Width", and "Slots Per Channel", and how that matches or does not match to my possible RAM choice, below). The `NA` values going down the columns, intersecting with `Non-ECC` rows make me concerned for amount of RAM supported:

[image: Populating UDIMM (ECC/Non-ECC) Memory Modules Table]

My questions, in the context of Non-ECC RAM, are:

1. Is it saying I can only use 1333 MHz RAM with this processor?
2. Can I use 4 sticks per installed CPU? or is there a limit of 2 per CPU?

I'm thinking [1333 MHz RAM](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231556) is required, but can I use faster RAM ([like 1666 MHz](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231568)?)

Comment: 1) Yes 2) See your screenshot(s), you can use 2 per channel, 3 per channel, or 4 per channel.

Comment: @Ramhound -- 1) Thanks! 2) I saw them, but some of the terms are not clicking in my brain -- I see `2 Slots Per Channel` and `3 Slots Per Channel` and I also see `1DPC` and `2DPC`, but I don't see "4 Slots Per Channel" or "4DPC", so is it `2 Slots Per Channel` multiplied by `2DPC` to get "4 dimms per processor" or something?!

Comment: @Ramhound -- and if I'm correct above, then why isn't it saying "6 dimms per processor" (`3 Slots Per Channel` multiplied by `2DPC`) (obviously not possible because that configuration is indicated as invalid in the first table, but there are also only 8 DIMM slots on the board, so 12 is not even physically possible... :-/

Comment: `then why isn't it saying "6 dimms per processor"` - Because the [motherboard](http://images10.newegg.com/NeweggImage/ProductImage/13-182-670-01.jpg) can only support 8 modules in total, so it makes no sense, to list something that physically can't be done.  I will be honest I don't understand the confusion.  the motherboard only supports 64 GB of NON-ECC memory, which is what your question about, which means the highest capacity possible would be 8x8GB modules.

Comment: @Ramhound -- I don't want to frustrate you, but I can't figure why there is even anything in that last column? What is its meaning, if not "6 dimms per processor"? (which we've both already pointed out is impossible)

Comment: I don't see "6 dimms per processor" in either screenshot you provided.

Comment: "6 dimms per processor" is never stated in the manual you provided.

Comment: @ramhound - I understand that. It also doesn't say anything about 4 dimms in the second table, which is the table I'm trying to understand. :-/

Comment: It does not need to implicitly say it supports 4 channels, the first table, covers that configuration.  if you understand `6 dimms per processor` never appears in the document, where are you getting that from, I am starting to wonder if this is a real question.

Comment: @ramhound - thanks for your patience. I'm missing something critical so I'll look at it a couple more times and see if I can either answer my own question or clarify what I'm not understanding. Thanks again